# Adobe CQ6 (AEM6). Cut and Paste from one parsys to another causes Unspecified error

Tags: java, adobe, aem, sling

I try to cut and paste text component from one parsys to another on the same page and I get Unspecified error.
If I copy, paste all OK.

How could I fix it?

I am using classic UI and AEM with SP1. My permissions are set correctly. Actually it is reproduced only on one PROD server during move from one parsys to another. In our continuous integration queue we have three servers. The first server DEV and the second server TEST are on our side and we have full access. The third server PROD is on customer side, we do not have full access and work with customer IT guys. Described issue is reproduced only on PROD server.

In JavaScript console I get

> POST /temporary-test/temp/jcr:content/par/ 500
>   (Internal Server Error)  post @   widgets.js:90381
>   CQ.wcm.EditBase.createParagraph   @   widgets.js:149003
>   CQ.wcm.EditBase.moveParagraph @   widgets.js:148900
>   handler   @   widgets.js:145049 EXTUTIL.Event.fire    @   widgets.js:4777
>   EXTUTIL.Observable.fireEvent  @   widgets.js:4418
>   CQ.Ext.menu.BaseItem.CQ.Ext.extend.onClick    @   widgets.js:65082
>   CQ.Ext.menu.Menu.CQ.Ext.extend.onClick    @   widgets.js:64288 h  @   wid

In server log I have

> 16.01.2015 12:31:15.160 *ERROR* [172.16.120.105 [1421411475091] POST /temp/jcr%3acontent/par/ HTTP/1.1]
>   org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation
>   Exception during response processing.
>   org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit
>   changes to session.   at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverContext.commit(ResourceResolverContext.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.commit(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1109)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.servlets.post.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.cognifide.cq.includefilter.DynamicIncludeFilter.doFilter(DynamicIncludeFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.cognifide.slice.core.internal.filter.ContextRequstFilter.doFilter(ContextRequstFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sap.dx.core.servlet.downloadasset.DownloadAssetFilter.doFilter(DownloadAssetFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: OakAccess0000: Access denied     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.newRepositoryException(SessionDelegate.java:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:538)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.perform(SessionImpl.java:417)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.perform(SessionImpl.java:414)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:414)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.base.SessionProxyHandler$SessionProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionProxyHandler.java:113)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.save(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:509)
>     ... 134 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakAccess0000:
>   Access denied     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.PermissionValidator.checkPermissions(PermissionValidator.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.PermissionValidator.propertyChanged(PermissionValidator.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.propertyChanged(VisibleValidator.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.propertyChanged(EditorDiff.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareProperties(SegmentNodeState.java:549)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.process(EditorDiff.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.MoveAwarePermissionValidator$MoveContext.diff(MoveAwarePermissionValidator.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.MoveAwarePermissionValidator$MoveContext.processAdd(MoveAwarePermissionValidator.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.MoveAwarePermissionValidator$MoveContext.access$300(MoveAwarePermissionValidator.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.MoveAwarePermissionValidator.childNodeAdded(MoveAwarePermissionValidator.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.VisibleValidator.childNodeAdded(VisibleValidator.java:32)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeEditor.childNodeAdded(CompositeEditor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeAdded(EditorDiff.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord$3.childNodeChanged(MapRecord.java:430)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:536)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.process(EditorDiff.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorHook.processCommit(EditorHook.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.prepare(SegmentNodeStore.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.optimisticMerge(SegmentNodeStore.java:373)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore$Commit.execute(SegmentNodeStore.java:429)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStore.merge(SegmentNodeStore.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.state.ProxyNodeStore.merge(ProxyNodeStore.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.commit(MutableRoot.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.commit(SessionDelegate.java:390)
>     at
>   org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:536)
>     ... 145 common frames omitted

Comment: Which components are you using? Btw. have you installed SP1?

The server log indicates that you are missing permissions to move the component node, but if your permissions are set correctly and this happens with foundation components then I bet that your are running into a touch UI bug.

SP 1 fixed a touch UI move issue CQ-18833 and a couple of paste issue when assets are involved. I was unable to reproduce with a blank aem6 + SP1.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I am using classic UI and AEM with SP1. My permissions are set correctly. Actually it is reproduced only on one server during move from one parsys to another. In our continuous integration queue we have three servers. The first server DEV and the second server TEST are on our side and we have full access. The third server PROD is on customer side, we do not have full access and work with customer IT guys. Described issue is reproduced only on PROD server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issues with permissions in groups.
Old version of OAK made wrong merge.

Last hot fix fro AEM 6 was installed.
OAK 1.0.8 was installed.

Such privileges were added:

rep:privileges="{Name}[jcr:versionManagement,jcr:lockManagement,jcr:modifyProperties]"

Comment: I would upvote, but you currently have 404 reputation